# What does the "null" area correspond to in the source-map-explorer visualisation for my React project, and why is it so big?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, aws-amplify

I have been working on a relatively straightforward React project, which has about 8 components, and uses a relatively small number of commonly used plugins (including styled-components, react-spring and AWS- Amplify)

I have installed and run source-map-explorer to see why my build is over 3MB, and the resulting visualization shows over ***2MB of my bundle being taken up by 'null'***.

***Could someone explain what 'null' refers to in this case?*** My guess is that it is the size of my package, but I can't imagine why it would be so large.

Also, if anyone knew of any nifty resource on how to reduce the size of the remaining 1MB of node-modules on a CRA project, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, it was an AWS Amplify issue. My app was exclusively using the API functionality, but I was importing the entire library.

In my code, I changed:

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify"
```

into

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core"
import API from "@aws-amplify/api"
```

and my bundle size was reduced from over 3MB to 679kb.

Not sure why it appeared as 'null' in the source-map-explorer, but this might help anyone using AWS Amplify and encountering an issues with bundle size. Other resources I found helpful:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/wiki/Amplify-modularization

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/122